# Floating effects on web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good Morning. I am a student of web development and I am curious to know with which technologies it is possible to realize this floating effect as in this site: https://www.fbiz.com.br/

Could any of you show me a code as an example?

Comment: You could just take a look at the source code or sources of the page itself and see, what they use.

Comment: You might find more resources online when search for "parallax effect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the (minified) source code, they are using a JavaScript that applies a `transform` CSS style to the 'floating' elements as the user scrolls.

Their JavaScript code might look something like this (overly simplified):

```
let element = document.querySelector('.foo');

window.onscroll = function(){
    let value = window.scrollY / 30 + 'px';

    element.style.transform = 'translateY(' + value + ')';
}
```